# Angular virtual scrolling error: viewdestroyederror: attempt to use a destroyed view: detectchanges

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using virtual scrolling from the cdk inside a trigger-opening sidenav on a mat-radio element, this is about the code:

ts -

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-generic-options-list',
  templateUrl: './generic-options-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generic-options-list.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class GenericOptionsListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() options: MultiSelectOption[];

  _options: MultiSelectOption[];
...
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshOptions();
  }

private refreshOptions() {
    this._options = this.options;
...
}
```

template -

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="30" class="scroll-viewport" *ngIf="type === 'single'">
<mat-radio-group >
    <mat-radio-button 
    *ngFor="let option of selected"
    [value]="option"
    [checked]="true"
    (click)="onRadioOptionClick(option)">
  {{option.val}}
</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button 
  *cdkVirtualFor="let option of _options"
      [value]="option"
      [checked]="false"
      (click)="onRadioOptionClick(option)"
      class="scroll-item"
      >
    {{option.val}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

and of course the proper css.

and anytime the above component disappears (apparently not destroyed as its not activating the onDestroy method when it does so) fro the parent component for a known reason (it should) then i get this error and the sidenav gets stuck and wont close. (and all kind of other weird things), I saw somewhere that using the onPush would solve it but it didn't.
What's the correct way of fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

In your .html file

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

In your .ts file

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Basic virtual scroll */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CdkVirtualScrollOverviewExample {
  items = Array.from({length: 100000}).map((_, i) => `Item #${i}`);
}
```

Add some custome css also if you want in you .css file

```
.example-viewport {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.example-item {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Just try to follow these steps in your logic

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but i know the documentation and everything is according to that, still the problem occurs, if theres another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

solved. the problem was already fixed by angular team and my cdk was not up to date, updating the cdk fixed that.